# Turtlebot: Live USB Install can reconfigure for ASUS Xtion Pro?

Tags: ros, installation, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have turtlebot and I use live USB Install(ROS groovy) which I have got when I buy turtlebot, Now I want to change Kinect to ASUS Xtion Pro , what should I do? I tested with turtle_follower with ASUS Xtion Pro, nothing happens , I aslo use command "rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure" , it just recognised the follower_velocity parameter, after I do like this step in this web [www.isep.ipp.pt/roswiki/turtlebot%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29groovy%282f%29Asus%2820%29Setup.html](http://www.isep.ipp.pt/roswiki/turtlebot%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29groovy%282f%29Asus%2820%29Setup.html), and command "rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure", it recognised the camera parameter, but turtlebot didnt anything.
Must I use 'Deb Installation'? Because I see ' Live USB Installation: This is pending information/testing of the live usb release.' for ASUS Xtion Pro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103071/turtlebot:-live-usb-install-can-reconfigure-for-asus-xtion-pro???/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you used the Live CD the instructions should be similar to the Debian install. It may require some slight tweaks but should work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0